# Cannot generate ExtJS application

Tags: exception, extjs

folks!

I'm having a trouble while trying to use `sencha -d -s /data/html/blablabal/ext-4.0 generate app Skeleton /data/html/Skeleton` and generate a skeleton for my existing application, that was created in past in very unlucky way :-(

When I invoke above mentioned command line, I always get this:

```
`

> sencha -d -s /data/html/hdbdesktop/ext-4.0 generate app Skeleton /data/html/Skeleton 
[DBG]       found sencha.cfg at /home/akosenkov/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250
[DBG]       Checking for framework config overrides
Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.250
[DBG]       found sencha.cfg at /home/akosenkov/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250
[DBG]       Checking for framework config overrides
[DBG]       creating workspace at '/data/html/Skeleton'
[ERR]       Failed to determine framework name.  Please ensure this command was issued from either a framework or application directory

com.sencha.exceptions.ExState: Failed to determine framework name.  Please ensure this command was issued from either a framework or application directory
    at com.sencha.command.BaseConfigCommands.mustGetFrameworkName(BaseConfigCommands.java:143)
    at com.sencha.command.generator.GeneratorCommands$WorkspaceCommand.execute(GeneratorCommands.java:60)
    at com.sencha.command.generator.GeneratorCommands$AppCommand.execute(GeneratorCommands.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:78)
    at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
    at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
    at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:71)
```

`

I'm using "normal" ExtJS ( i.e. this is NOT Sencha Touch ).

What's wrong?

Sincerely thankful for any hints! :-)

NB: I had a thorough study of http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#/guide/command_app and everything, that have even a little relation to subject...

Comment: what directory are you issuing this command from?

Comment: I had tried the /data/html/hdbdesktop/ext-4.0 ( where SDK is located ), but this gives no desired result :-( The same is true for any other directory, that I ever able to came up with... And what is a correct place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what the docs say:

**Current Directory**

In many cases, Sencha Cmd requires you have a specific current directory. Or it may just need to know details about the relevant SDK. This can be determined easily when Sencha Cmd is run form an extracted SDK folder or from a generated application.

The following is a summary of these needs organized by what is required and the commands that have that requirement.

```
Require knowledge of which SDK is in use
    sencha generate app
    sencha compile
A generated application root folder
    sencha generate ... (all commands other than app and workspace)
    sencha app ...
```

The commands that require the current directory to be a generated application root folder will fail if not run from such a folder.

When a command requires knowledge of the SDK but you are not currently in an extracted SDK folder or an application root folder, you need to use the -sdk switch like so:

sencha -sdk /path/to/sdk ...

**Wrong Current Directory**

A common mistake is to perform a command that requires the current directory to be either an extracted SDK directory or an application directory and yet not be in such a directory. If this requirement is not met, Sencha Cmd will display an error and exit.

Note that a valid application directory is one that was generated by Sencha Cmd, or one that exactly follows that structure.

Answer (score 0):

Having had exactly the same issue, it turns out that `sencha` needs the SDK folder to be identical to that of the extracted zip.

So while a folder name of `ext-4.0` or just `ext` won't work, `ext-4.1.1a` does.